# Is there a workaround for pinging a database every few minutes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, node-mysql

So, I have a NodeJS MySql system, which pings the database every 10 Minutes (might set that to one Minute) to not lose the connection, but that is not the code quality I like to write.
So, now I am asking myself, if there is any way to avoid that.
I have no plan on what Pools are, or what they do. I've seen them in a few other posts but not looked in to them, is that the only option?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Afaik pools are used to manage more than one db connection. However your question is unclear: why are you losing the connection in the first place? What type of program is your node code? Is it a web server?

Comment: I am making a webserver, that communicates with my Database. I am loosing the connection, due to MySql breaking the connection after some time, due to inactivity.

Comment: What about creating a new connection if the old one is down instead?

Comment: polling the database is not the solution then, you should undestand why mysql is dropping the connection and fix it. It is not the expected behaviour for mysql.

Comment: In you title and description you made mistakes like `ther ==> there` and `wich ==> which`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should learn about connection pools - they are a good tool for managing a connection (or a bunch of them to support concurrency).

Connections - whether to databases or to any other remote systems - are unreliable. They can come and go, and you must not assume that a connection will live forever. Hosts can sometimes be restarted, network links can go down, or a firewall may choose to terminate your TCP session.

Of course, you could implement a "connection recycler" that maintains a single connection and replaces it with a fresh one whenever it's closed. However, that would be unproductive since a pool already does that - only it typically manages more than 1 instance under the hood. It's a good excercise for learning purposes in any case.

A pool has another advantage - it can scale according to load, creating and destroying connections as needed. This lets you put less load on the database when the application load is low.

As a closing remark, if you use query builders (knex.js), object-relational mappers (sequelize, TypeORM), or other types of tools that abstract database access, they'll typically use a pool under the hood, anyway - so understanding this important layer of infrastructure is beneficial in the long run.